# How can I restrict access to a directory inside web root?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have an angular app and I concatenate and minify all of the angular.js files so it is more difficult for a user to "borrow" my code. I want to restrict access to my angular directory, which is inside the web root. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
app.get('/angular/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

The problem is that anyone can enter `mydomain.com/angular/controllers.js`, for example, and see the `controllers.js` file. I am a bit surprised since I thought that I specified in the routes to redirect the user when attempting to access any file inside the angular directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably your 'compiled' code is in e.g. /public? If so, don't include a route to /angular at all

Comment: I'm not explicitly providing a route to ``/angular``. But, I can still access that directory and see any file inside it.

Comment: Your files need to be available so the browser can interpret them, there is no way to prevent access and keep your app running if that is what you want to do

Comment: Why do you have `/angular` in the web root at all then, if it is all built and minified into another folder?

Comment: `/angular/*` will block other stuff, but you'll need to have the compiled code in another directory

Comment: I keep in the web root for testing. I don't want my errors to say "Error on line 1 column 25834". I basically just comment out all of my included scripts, then uncomment out the concatenated/minified script when pushing to production.

Comment: Testing and debugging should not be done on your producion server. Keep the source files while developing, but don't publish them on your production server.

Comment: You could also use sourcemaps so you can debug properly even while using a concatenated build.

Answer (score 0):

A user can just open the web inspector for their browser and read your code once it's running in their browser so doing this won't solve your problem.

You should instead minify and uglify the code into a single bundle perhaps? I do this using browserify as you can see in this project https://github.com/evanshortiss/cordova-angular-browserify. Then you can just run the code that has been bundled through uglify.

If you don't want to use browserify you could just find another way such as reading the JS files in your html file, then read them all and dump them into a single .js file in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

As there are beautify solutions, Minify or uglify can't be good solutions!

You can move your private files/folders into directories which are not http accessible.

Hope this helps! :)